# Нужна помощь в разделении блоков div

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Никак не пойму как разделить div левого меню и div контента. При полном размере экрана блок .content прячется за .sidebar-menu-left. Что я делаю не так?

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.content {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    width: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}

.sidebar-menu-left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 550px;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="sidebar-menu-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quasi non praesentium, animi soluta aspernatur, iste distinctio beatae nemo molestiae quidem expedita facere possimus delectus ipsam voluptates eos saepe rem.</div>
         
         <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, molestiae labore natus animi quos est culpa eos quisquam omnis voluptates vero ut iusto sunt ad provident necessitatibus non quam eveniet!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для родительского элемента этих двух текстовых блоков задаёшь:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: space-around;
```

---

Поменяй свой CSS на этот:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100vw;
}

.content {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    width: 40%;
    height: 1000px;
}

.sidebar-menu-left {
    width: 40%;
    height: 550px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Для родителя **.wrapper** добавить **display: flex;**

Для **.sidebar-menu-left** добавить **position: relative; width: 35%;**

Для **.content** добавить **margin: 0 0 0 30px;**

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.content {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    width: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.sidebar-menu-left {
  position: relative;
width: 35%;
    height: 550px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="sidebar-menu-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quasi non praesentium, animi soluta aspernatur, iste distinctio beatae nemo molestiae quidem expedita facere possimus delectus ipsam voluptates eos saepe rem.</div>
         
         <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, molestiae labore natus animi quos est culpa eos quisquam omnis voluptates vero ut iusto sunt ad provident necessitatibus non quam eveniet!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```